# How to set cookies in next.js in app route

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js

I was going through the documentation of app route of next.js and I found the following code.[image]

I says cookies must be set inside app/actions.js. My question is how to execute this piece of code and what is the use of `'use server'` in this piece of code.

Comment: The `use server` directive is used to define a so called "server action", a alpha feature introduced in Next.js 13.4, more can be found inside this [blog post](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-4#server-actions-alpha) or in the official documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions).